# Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) python

Tags: python, angularjs, json

I'm newbie in python and trying to parse data in my application using these lines of codes

```
json_str = request.body.decode('utf-8') 
py_str = json.loads(json_str)
```

But I'm getting this error on `json.loads`

> Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

this is json formatted data that I send from angular app (Updated)

> Object { ClientTypeId: 6, ClientName: "asdasd", ClientId: 0, PhoneNo: "123", FaxNo: "123", NTN: "1238", GSTNumber: "1982", OfficialAddress: "sads", MailingAddress: "asdasd", RegStartDate: "17-Aug-2016", 15 more… }

these are the values that I get in `json_str`

> ClientTypeId=5&ClientName=asdasd&ClientId=0&PhoneNo=123&FaxNo=123&NTN=123&GSTNumber=12&OfficialAddress=adkjh&MailingAddress=adjh&RegStartDate=09-Aug-2016&RegEndDate=16-Aug-2016&Status=1&CanCreateUser=true&UserQuotaFor=11&UserQuotaType=9&MaxUsers=132123&ApplyUserCharges=true&ApplyReportCharges=true&EmailInvoice=true&BillingType=1&UserCharges=132&ReportCharges=123&MonthlyCharges=123&BillingDate=16-Aug-2016&UserSessionId=324

I don't know what's wrong in it.. can anyone mention what's the mistake is??

Comment: Well, that's not JSON…

Comment: Why do you think `json_str` is JSON-encoded data when it clearly isn't? What do you want to achieve with your code?

Comment: I don't know why it is converting like this.. I'm sending json values from my angular app (check updated part)

Comment: Well then your problem is that you are using Angular wrong, or don't understand the big picture. You are sending data "form-encoded", not JSON-encoded, and your server-side code behaves correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is not [JSON-formatted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), not even the one you included in your updated answer.  Your data is a JavaScript-object, not an encoded string.  Please note the "N" in JSON: Notation -- it is a format inspired from how data is written in JavaScript code, but runtime JavaScript data is not represented in JSON.  The "JSON" you pasted is how your browser represents the object to you, it is not proper JSON (that would be `{"ClientTypeId": 6, ...}` -- note the quotes around the property name).

When sending this data to the server, you have to encode it. You think you are sending it JSON-encoded, but you aren't.  You are sending it "web form encoded" (data of type [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type)).

Now either you have to learn how to send the data in JSON format from Angular, or use the correct parsing routine in Python: [`urllib.parse.parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs).  Depending on the library you are using, there might be a convenience method to access the data as well, as this is a common use case.

Comment: …or presumably there's some method on `request` which allows you direct access to the parsed data already…

Comment: @deceze Yes, presumably. I refused the temptation to guess :) -- Do you happen to have a link to the docs at hand?

Comment: Not knowing what library the OP is using exactly, I refuse to guess as well.

Comment: my bad... yes the issue was in data sending.. i was actually using jquery ajax to send data instead of angular $http.. by replacing $.ajax with $http resolved my issue.. Thank you for pointing out it

Comment: Instead of deleting this dumb question, let it be here for anyone else dumb like me.. may be it'll help someone to resolve issue and save their time...